# Macro to outline a cell in pgfplotstable

Tags: tables, macros, pgfplotstable

Still struggling with the `\expandafter` and `\noexpand` tex macros.

I'm trying to put a table together using `pgfplotstable`.

In this case the code is something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\def\outline{\noexpand\fbox{{##1}}}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&,header=false]{%
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\%
5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\%
9 & 10 & 11 & 12\\%
}\mytable

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
debug,
column name={},
every row 2 column 1/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\outline}}
]\mytable

\end{document}
```

and gives the error `you can't use macro parameter character in horizontal restricted mode`. I f I escape the `##1` it replaces cell contents with `##1`.

What I'm trying to do is eventually have a line that says something like:

`every row 2 column 1/.style=\outline` and a macro along the lines of

```
\def\outline{%
\{postproc cell content.style=%
\{@cell content=\noexpand\fbox{##1}\}\}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the wrong track: the problem is unrelated to expansion control.

The problem is that your invocation of `\outline` does not communicate the argument - and the definition of `\outline` has no argument defined, although it requires one.

Once you fix these two points, you can come back to escaping `#1` by `##1`.

This here appears to work as desired:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\def\outline#1{\fbox{{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&,header=false]{%
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\%
5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\%
9 & 10 & 11 & 12\\%
}\mytable

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
debug,
column name={},
every row 2 column 1/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\outline{##1}}}
]\mytable

\end{document}
```

[image]

I changed the definition of `\outline` (`\def` requires you to list the expected arguments in the definition) and the invocation of `\outline`. Note that the latter really requires `##1` (because `#1` is the argument to `every row 2 column 1` in that context and you want the argument to `postproc cell content`).

---

*EDIT*:

concerning the second part of your question and your comment on this answer: yes, it might be possible to define a style by means of a macro which expands to key-value assignments. But it is clearly not a best-practice. In fact, if it works, it might be luck.

If you want to have some sort of style which says "outline this cell", then you might be better of with something of sorts

```
% preamble:
\pgfplotstableset{
   outline/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\outline{##1}}}
}

%code:
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
debug,
column name={},
every row 2 column 1/.style={outline},
]\mytable
```

Comment: Thanks @ChristianFeuersanger. A follow on from the second half of my question: when I change that to `\def\outline#1{@cell content=\fbox{{#1}}}` and the `pgfplotstabletypeset` to `every row 2 column 1/.style={postproc cell content/.style={\outline{##1}}` I get an `illegal parameter number in definition of outline` error. Do you know why that is? I'm eventually trying to get everything from `postproc cell content..` built into the \outline macro

Comment: Do you mean something along the lines of my edit?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @ChristianFeuersanger. That is exactly what I needed. I just had a d'oh! moment when I saw your post. I'd forgotten how elegant pgf and pgfplotstable are for this stuff.